# Why people review questions after 1000 review badge

Tags: discussion, badges

There is a badge **Steward**, anyone who reviews posts upto **1000** they will get this badge.

My question is why people reviewing continuously even after getting **Steward** badge?

This badge could not be awarded multiple times on same type of reviews.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Because people don't take care of the website just for badges and fake internet points. They actually care.

Comment: It was just curiosity that why people are still reviewing after getting badge. I appreciate your input. Yes this could be the reason +1 for that. But I have seen some people who have 1000+ reviews and still they do not even see the what is edited and just approve the edits.